# Genre of "Someone Like You" (Van Morrison)

Tags: identify-this-genre, piano

The Song is "Someone Like You" from Van Morrison. I would like to know the genre of this song and if could direct me to videos where this song is being played using a keyboard/piano, it would be of great help!

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9KHk9d2pQFU

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Van Morisson is mainly a **Rock** artist and this nice song sounds like a ballad, I suggest you to look at the [Rock Ballad](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=rock+ballads) subgenre.

Then, if you are looking to piano covers of this song, you can try to find ones on [Youtube: "someone like you van morrison piano cover"](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=someone+like+you+van+morrison+piano+cover). A this time I've found :

- Cover by [Larry L](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YwGXWGdMSPk)
- Cover by [The Sun Harmonic](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oh1KYIN0PgM)

Just keep scrolling and you will find other covers...